# How to call compose message activity in tabView?

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am making an application in android Source Code(Gingerbread). which requires the compose message activity in tab View.
I have tried as follows:

> > Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
> >     intent.setClassName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
> >
> > StickyTabs.setTab(intent, TAB_INDEX_MESSAGES);

the logcat shows me the error:

> >
>   03-19 10:08:02.321: E/AndroidRuntime(151): java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.android.mms (with uid 10004) to be run in process android.process.acore (with uid 10007)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have permissions in your AndroidManifest for accessing MMS. "Request" permission to use MMS in the Manifest and the Exception should disappear.

did U add permission

```
"android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"
"android.permission.SEND_SMS"
```

Comment: Tobias, Thanks for the quick reply.
I have mentioned the activity in manifest like "        <activity android:name="com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>"

Comment: Yes but you also need to declare which permissions your application need to run. For example you might want this permission: MESSAGES  Used for permissions that allow an application to send messages on behalf of the user or intercept messages being received by the user.

Comment: Have you found any documentation about StickyTabs? Since it's not an official API maybe that has something to do with the security problems? I am not sure what StickyTabs really do, but it seems like they integrate with other applications and that might cause this problem?

Comment: I have found that the problem is with the userID. Android have assigned a unique userId to each app. That's why we are not able to run the activity from sms package into Contact Package.
I have read about the "SharedUserId' which can solve this problem.. So I am trying that....

Answer (score 0):

If you have a phone number and you want to compose SMS for this No, and you are somewhere in another activity, then use this line of code, which will call and open the SMS Composing activity and will also pass your mobile number to whom you want to send the SMS.

```
Intent sms_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
Uri data = Uri.parse("sms:"+phone_No);        
intent.setData(data);      
startActivity(sms_intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the future, please do not use bold formatting for your **entire** answer, and please use properly-spelled English in your posts. I've edited this one for you.